# Way to make sure git pull always overwrites one specifc local file

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

In repository I have a set of file. One of them gets modified by running some operation.
How can I configure the git to make sure that whenever someone does a pull the one file should get overwritten by the version currently in repo.

i.e.
Person A makes some change - file "spec" is modified.
Person A pushes everything to origin.

Person B was also making some changes now he needs to accept the changes.
Person B does pull.
For person B his current copy of file "spec" should get overwritten (without merge attempt).
Now B would do somethings that will modify file "spec" and the push everything to origin.

File "spec" should never get merged. (Though modified file needs to be pushed to origin).
I need this spec file to be in the same repo.

Comment: You're either asking how to avoid modifying a tracked file or how to avoid merging a file, and in both cases, the answer is, you don't.  Git doesn't recommend doing either of those things.

Comment: May be git does not reccommend it, but this is my use case and thats what I want to achieve. otherwise every merge has the potential to corrupt my data in the file "spec". I was hoping that there might be something similar to gitignore where pull would force overwrite but push will work as expected.

THanks for confirming it is not available in git

Comment: You can do it with a custom merge driver as mentioned in the answer I linked, but of course any hosting platform you use won't support that.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to delete a certain file's local changes and revert it to the git head, you don't need `git pull` -- `git checkout <commit> -- <file>` will change the specified file to whatever it was at the specified commit.

`git pull`'s function is to update the entire working directory, not one specific file.
If the remote has been updated, and changes to any file have not been committed, it would be reverted on `pull`.